# How to compile coins from github? (linux mint/ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I tried to install a couple of coins from GitHub code, but none succeeded. For example, this (or other): https://github.com/muddafudda/PayCon

Please step-by step guide

Comment: You need to read the file `doc/build-unix.txt` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the required dependancies first

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y git make g++ build-essential libminiupnpc-dev

sudo apt-get install -y libdb++-dev libssl-dev libboost1.48-all libboost-chrono1.48-dev
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/cryptotech/PayCon.git 

cd PayCon/src/leveldb

sh build_detect_platform build_config.mk ./

cd

cd PayCon/src

make -f makefile.unix
```

Comment: It would be helpfull, if you told him where you got this info from.

Comment: Thank you for success. Missing this place a coin description: "PayCon cd / src / leveldb

build_detect_platform build_config.mk sh ./ "
That there is not a signatory to the developer.

Comment: In addition, after the start I get: 
"Error: To use PayCond, you must set a rpcpassword in the configuration file: /home/droid/.PayCon/PayCon.conf
It is recommended you use the following random password:
rpcuser=PayConrpc
rpcpassword=BciiVvwLyPyHdWD35K18WHbADcckvkEn6hLjckbZoFX8
(you do not need to remember this password)

Comment: That is fairly typical message from any Altcoin - you just need to create a file /home/droid/.PayCon/PayCon.conf and put in the data it says. You can also add more startup configuration parameters in there rather than on the command line.

Comment: Fine. Im create that .conf file in ./PayCon folder. How to starting? Where is the wallet?

Comment: The conf file must be create on the default data dir .PayCon then cd PayCon/src and run ./PayCond the PayCon daemon which is command line controlled,so if you want a wallet with graphical user interface you need to compile the PayCon-qt

Answer (score 0):

You gave instructions for a daemon.

cd PayCon

qmake

make

That should spit out a qt

Just make sure the permissions in build_detect_platform are open, if not, change them.

Comment: Plus, on Linux, you do not have to build leveldb before you compile. That is strictly Windows.

Comment: The build-unix.md doc builds the daemon and Qt and other tools too